# Define MongoDB Collection in REST API GET Request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, http, express

I have data in 2 seperate collections stored in the same MongoDB database. Is there a way to define in the HTTP GET request query string from which collection the data should be retrieved.
I use the following JS to process the query:

```
const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
const collection = db.collection('THIS should come from the query string');
collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  callback(docs);   
});
  };
};
```

The App is setup in Node.js using express

```
dataRouter.route('/data')
.post(function(req, res){
    var query =req.query;
    //console.log(query);

    getResult(query, function(data){
        console.log('query done');
        //console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    });
    module.exports = {
        query: query
    };
});

app.use('/api', dataRouter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you shared, you are declaring a POST method, not a GET.
Any case, in a GET method you could send a query parameter that identify which collection you want to use.
Image you send a query param called collection

```
http://myhost/data?collection=1
```

and you could extract that query param with:

```
var numberCollection = req.query.collection;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I got i working now. `var query =req.query` has actually already been used to query the collection which was hard coded at the moment. But now i have build an array `query.push(req.query.variable, req.query.coll);` and this works now